# Unable to build Xamarin solution on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Please tell me how to fix the problem. I updated Xamarin forms dll.

I get the following error:

> Error  error: cannot find symbol
>       private native void n_onInflate (android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat p0, android.view.View p1);
>     symbol:   class ViewStubCompat
>     location: package android.support.v7.widget
>       obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\ViewStubCompat_OnInflateListenerImplementor.java
>   Error    error: cannot find symbol
>       public void onInflate (android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat p0, android.view.View p1)
>     symbol:   class ViewStubCompat
>     location: package android.support.v7.widget
>       obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\ViewStubCompat_OnInflateListenerImplementor.java
>   Error    error: package android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout does not exist
>           android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.OnAttachListener
>       obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\ContentFrameLayout_OnAttachListenerImplementor.java
>   Error    error: package android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup does not exist
>           android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsViewGroup.OnFitSystemWindowsListener
>       \obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\FitWindowsViewGroup_OnFitSystemWindowsListenerImplementor.java
>   Error    error: package android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat does not exist
>           android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat.OnInflateListener
>       \obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\widget\ViewStubCompat_OnInflateListenerImplementor.java

Answer (score 0):

Did you "update all Nuget packages"? This will download the incorrect versions of the Google libs. You will have to update the Forms packages manually, they will then pull in the required dependencies.

Also make sure you update the packages in *all* of your projects (the actual Forms project and the platform specific ones).

Finally, clean the solution and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

James Montemagno explains the issue perfectly here:

[Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/169816/#Comment_169816)

I suspect you have updated all packages which will require manual intervention as described by @Krumelur above.